# How to fix the exception "Literals of type 'E' are currently not supported" while applying regex_replace on a dataframe in Scala?

Tags: regex, postgresql, scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe created from reading an RDBMS table as below:

```
val dataDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", connectionUrl)
                                                .option("dbtable", s"(${query}) as year2017")
                                                .option("user", devUserName)
                                                .option("password", devPassword)
                                                .option("numPartitions",15)
                                                .load()
```

Before ingesting the data into the Hive tables on HDFS, we were asked to apply a regex_replace pattern on the columns of the dataframe that are of String datatype. This is how I applied it:

```
val regExpr = dataDF.schema.fields.map { x =>
  if (x.dataType == StringType)
  "regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(%s, E'[\\\\n]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\\\r]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\\\t]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\\\cA]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\\\ca]+', ' ', 'g' ) as %s".format(x.name, x.name)
  else
    x.name
}
dataDF.selectExpr(regExpr:_*)
```

But when I execute the code, it ends with following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
Literals of type 'E' are currently not supported.(line 1, pos 88)

== SQL ==
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(period_name, E'[\\n]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\r]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\t]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\cA]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\ca]+', ' ', 'g' ) as period_name
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^
```

I printed the schema using: println(dataDF.schema). The code is identifying the String column correctly where you can see the column name: `period_name`

```
Schema: StructType(StructField(forecast_id,LongType,true), StructField(period_num,DecimalType(15,0),true), StructField(period_name,StringType,true), StructField(drm_org,StringType,true), StructField(ledger_id,LongType,true), StructField(currency_code,StringType,true))
```

The requirement is to remove spaces in multiple formats.
Data in the String columns could have values with spaces in multiple formats.

```
1,             b,c,   d,

e,Ωåf
```

There are multiple spaces, tab space, value occurring after a new line, removing the special characters if there are any, etc.,
The above line should be converted to: 1, b,c, d, e, f

The table read is present on postgres database. I tried to understand why is E causing the exception but I am not able to get a clue. Could anyone let me know how can I fix this exception ?

Comment: what are you trying to do using so many nested regexp_replace? can you explain that with an example?

Comment: I am very new to regex actually. This is being used in a code that is already working. I was told to apply it before ingesting the data into Hive. I just used it in the same way. If you would like to look at the existing/old code, I can add that part as well.

Comment: can you give examples on what are you trying to replace with what?

Comment: and regexp_replace is an inbuilt function to be applied on spark dataframe columns and you are applying on your schema

Comment: what I can suggest you right now is to select columns with stringtype and use foldleft and withColumn and use regexp_replace inside withColumn

Comment: I understand your suggestion but how can I apply (foldleft,with column) only on String cols of my dataframe ?

Comment: please see the answer below. more or less it should help you to get into right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For test purpose I created a dataframe with the provided string with special characters in *col3* column as

```
+----+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|col1|col2|col3                                                                |
+----+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|a   |1   |1,          -   b,c,   d,
                 |
                 |e,Ωåf|
+----+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

then as suggested in the comments to *select columns with stringtype* and *use foldleft and withColumn* and *use `regexp_replace` inside withColumn*, you can do the following

```
//getting column names which are string type
val stringColumns = df.schema.fields.filter(_.dataType == StringType).map(_.name)
//applying regex to replace all characters except digits, characters (a to z and A to Z) and commas
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val finaldf = stringColumns.foldLeft(df){(tempdf, colName) => tempdf.withColumn(colName, regexp_replace(col(colName), "[ ](?=[ ])|[^,A-Za-z0-9]+", ""))}
```

thus `finaldf` would be as

```
+----+----+-----------+
|col1|col2|col3       |
+----+----+-----------+
|a   |1   |1,b,c,d,e,f|
+----+----+-----------+
```

You can change the *regex pattern* `[ ](?=[ ])|[^,A-Za-z0-9]+` according to your need. Right now `,A-Za-z0-9` characters are only **not removed**

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: yes and do let me know if any problem and if it works don't forget to accept and upvote

Comment: I tried it like below:     val stringColumns = dataDF.schema.fields.filter(_.dataType == StringType).map(_.name)
    val finaldf = stringColumns.foldLeft(dataDF){(tempdf, colName) => tempdf.withColumn(colName, regexp_replace(col(colName), "\\\\n+", ""))} 
and getting the compile time error on the line: regexp_replace(col(colName),'\\s+',' ','g') with message: 'Cannot resolve symbol col' 

Is there anything I need to change ?

Comment: I have edited my answer . all you need is `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._`

Comment: Worked like a charm.